# How to perform a column calculation in a CALCULATE()

Tags: dax

My table looks like this:

```
Doc  Code 
A    61
A    61X  
B    62
B    61
C    61
C    62
C    62X
```

I am trying to create a column in DAX that just checks whether a Code contains an X by Doc.  So the result should look like this:

```
Doc  Code DAXColumn
A    61   TRUE
A    61X  TRUE
B    62   FALSE
B    61   FALSE
C    61   TRUE
C    62   TRUE
C    62X  TRUE
```

I want to do this:

```
DAXColumn = 
VAR currentDoc = Doc
RETURN
CALCULATE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("X",Doc)) = TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
FILTER(myTable,Doc = currentDoc))
```

It looks like I can't pass a column into the CALCULATE parameter.  How could I get the results I am looking for?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Column =
VAR _1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( _fact, CONTAINSSTRING ( _fact[Code], "X" ) ),
        [Doc],
        [Code]
    )
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE ( MAXX ( FILTER ( _1, [Doc] = MAX ( _fact[Doc] ) ), [Code] ) )
VAR _3 =
    SWITCH ( TRUE (), ISBLANK ( _2 ) = TRUE (), FALSE (), TRUE () )
RETURN
    _3
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion - I find this code a bit more readable so it's easier to understand at a glance what is going on.

```
Contains X := 
VAR _codes = 
    CALCULATETABLE ( 
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Code] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Doc] ) 
    )
VAR _filter = 
    FILTER ( 
        _codes ,
        CONTAINSSTRING ( [Code] , "X" )
    )
VAR _count = COUNTROWS ( _filter )
RETURN IF ( _count > 0 , TRUE , FALSE )
```

The logic:

1. Calculate a single column table with all values of `Code` for the current (row context) value of `Doc`
2. Apply a filter over the codes table looking for the desired string
3. Count the rows in the remaining table

If the count is zero, the `_count` variable will evaluate to blank. For a non-zero count we want to return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
DocHasX = 
    VAR tmp =
        CALCULATE(
            SUMX(
                Sheet1,
                FIND("X", Sheet1[Code], 1, 0) -- sum up the positions where X is found in each Code...
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1, Sheet1[Doc]) -- ... for all rows hat have the same Doc as the current row
        )
    RETURN tmp > 0
```

[image: Result]